# mysql use sum and max to find the highest paid invoice

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, max

i am trying to figure out how to get the MAX result of a SUM of values from a table in order to display the highest paid amount of a receipt. I also supposed to use subselect, but im getting confused. 
So far this query gets me everything i need displayed except for the max value. 
[This is the table (invoice+OD) need to be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljv5X.png)
[This is what i am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeGia.png)[This is what i should be getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS34H.png)

where can i add MAX() (of sum)?

```
SELECT invoicenumber invoice
     , invoicedate date
     , SUM(orderqty*ordersell) AS 'Invoice Total' 
  FROM invoice 
  JOIN orderdetail 
    ON invoice.invoiceid = orderdetail.invoiceid 
 GROUP 
    BY invoice ;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  All non-aggregated columns must be in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SUM or MAX in SELECT, you need to GROUP BY other columns:

```
SELECT invoicenumber AS invoice
 , invoicedate AS date
 , SUM(orderqty*ordersell) AS 'Invoice Total' 
FROM invoice 
JOIN orderdetail ON invoice.invoiceid = orderdetail.invoiceid 
GROUP BY invoicenumber,invoicedate;
```

Comment: but where would i insert the MAX function in order to only get the highest paid bill?

Comment: same as SUM in SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (adding on to the previous answer):

```
SELECT invoicenumber AS invoice
 , invoicedate AS date
 , SUM(orderqty*ordersell) AS 'Invoice Total' 
FROM invoice 
JOIN orderdetail ON invoice.invoiceid = orderdetail.invoiceid 
GROUP BY invoicenumber,invoicedate ORDER BY `Invoice Total` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

May not be too efficient, but returns the highest result only.

Comment: this definitely displays the highest result only which is great. is there any way to do this in a sub query without using the limit keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is close from what you where looking, but i think this would work (if i understood correctly what you are trying to achieve).

```
SELECT inv.invoicenumber,
       inv.invoice, 
       inv.invoicedate AS 'Date',
       MAX((SELECT ord.orderqty+ord.ordersell FROM DUAL)) AS 'Invoice Total' 
  FROM invoice inv
  JOIN orderdetail ord
    ON inv.invoice.invoiceid = ord.orderdetail.invoiceid 
 GROUP BY inv.invoice, 
          inv.invoice, 
          inv.invoicedate;
```